# Why Int and Float literals are allowed to be added, but Int and Float variables are not allowed to do the same in Swift?

Tags: swift, casting, swift5, type-safety

I tried adding an `Int` and `Float` literal in Swift and it compiled without any error :

```swift
var sum = 4 + 5.0 // sum is assigned with value 9.0 and type Double
```

But, when I tried to do the same with `Int` and `Float` variables, I got a compile-time error and I had to type-cast any one operand to the other one's type for it to work:

```swift
var i: Int = 4
var f:Float = 5.0
var sum = i + f // Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Float'
```

Why is it happening so ? Is it related to type safety in any way ?

Comment: What had you expected to happen? You have explicitly defined the types of each variable, for the compiler to make the addition work it would have had to override one of your type declarations and that would have been much worse, wouldn’t it?

Comment: So, to respect the explicitly specified type annotations, the compiler is asking us to type cast the variables explicitly, right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `var sum = 4 + 5.0` the compiler automatically converts 4 to a float as that is what is required to perform the operation.
Same happens if you write `var x: Float = 4`. The 4 is automatically converted to a float.

In second case, since you have explicitly defined the type of the variable, the compiler does not have the freedom to change is as per the requirement.

For solution, look at @Fabio 's answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want Double result:

```
let i: Int = 4
let f: Float = 5.0
let sum = Double(i) + Double(f)
print("This is the sum:", sum)
```

If you want Int result:

```
let i: Int = 4
let f: Float = 5.0
let sum = i + Int(f)
print("This is the sum:", sum)
```

Comment: Yeah I knew about this. But, I wanted to know why this warning wasn't generated when raw literals were used. @Suyash Medhavi's answer cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The document on Swift.org says:

> Type inference is particularly useful when you declare a constant or variable with an initial value. This is often done by assigning a literal value (or literal) to the constant or variable at the point that you declare it. (A literal value is a value that appears directly in your source code, such as 42 and 3.14159 in the examples below.)
>
> For example, if you assign a literal value of 42 to a new constant
> without saying what type it is, Swift infers that you want the
> constant to be an Int, because you have initialized it with a number
> that looks like an integer:

```
let meaningOfLife = 42 // meaningOfLife is inferred to be of type Int
```

> Likewise, if you don’t specify a type for a floating-point literal,
> Swift infers that you want to create a Double:

```
let pi = 3.14159 // pi is inferred to be of type Double Swift always
```

> chooses Double (rather than Float) when inferring the type of
> floating-point numbers.
>
> If you combine integer and floating-point literals in an expression, a
> type of Double will be inferred from the context:

```
> let anotherPi = 3 + 0.14159 // anotherPi is also inferred to be of
```

> type Double The literal value of 3 has no explicit type in and of
> itself, and so an appropriate output type of Double is inferred from
> the presence of a floating-point literal as part of the addition.

Comment: The question is more about the other case, when the type of the variable has been given.